# Log4j log custom level for specific user(s) in production

Tags: log4j

In production environment I'm only logging WARN and ERROR log messages.

I need to implement a mechanism that logs ALL log levels for (a) specific user(s).

I'm handling requests coming in from outside (not necessarily a servlet) and from the beginning I can retrieve the users name, so I'm able to put users name in MDC and it will go to the log messages.

However, I need to check if users name is in a predefined list of users (this list can actually dynamically be updated during runtime) and if the users name is in this list then I need to enable (for this user only) logging to be from fx. TRACE level (meaning all TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN and ERROR).

Is this possible?

**UPDATE #1**: We're using Spring Boot Log4j

**UPDATE #2**: Log4j config

```
LOG_PATTERN=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %X{context} ${PID} %5p %-10X{username} [%t] - %c{1}(%L): %m%n

log4j.rootCategory=INFO, amqp

log4j.category.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.category.com.acme=DEBUG

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/app.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=${LOG_PATTERN}

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=${LOG_PATTERN}

log4j.appender.amqp=org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j.AmqpAppender
log4j.appender.amqp.host=localhost
log4j.appender.amqp.port=5671
log4j.appender.amqp.username=username
log4j.appender.amqp.password=password
log4j.appender.amqp.virtualHost=vhost

log4j.appender.amqp.exchangeName=logging.pub
log4j.appender.amqp.exchangeType=topic
log4j.appender.amqp.routingKeyPattern=%c.%p
log4j.appender.amqp.declareExchange=false
log4j.appender.amqp.durable=true
log4j.appender.amqp.autoDelete=false
log4j.appender.amqp.contentType=text/plain
log4j.appender.amqp.generateId=false
log4j.appender.amqp.senderPoolSize=2
log4j.appender.amqp.maxSenderRetries=30
log4j.appender.amqp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.amqp.layout.ConversionPattern=${LOG_PATTERN}
```

Comment: SLF4J is only the Façade. What is your logging implementation / Bridge in use? Commons Logging? Log4j? Logback? I guess you should be able to define some filter for this at least in logback and log4j.

Comment: Sorry.... We're using Spring Boot Log4j (I've updated the question as well)

Comment: Will the user-specific Full log go to separate appenders? Like each user into a different file or something like that? Can we see your current log config?

Comment: The AMQP appender is the one that should take the log entries. I've updated the question with the log4j config content.

Comment: Another important question is: which version of log4j?

Comment: Log4j version is 1.2.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

After all the clarifications, the short answer is: no.

The very first check that is done by log4j's `trace/debug/.../error` methods is the **logger level**. If the log event level is below the logger configured level -- nothing else is done, the logging method returns. Message formatting, processing the diagnostic context, triggering appenders -- all come later, provided that there is anything to process. In log4j 1 it cannot be changed by configuration.

In log4j 2 we have global filters, which are checked prior to the logger level test -- although I don't know if they'd be fit for this kind of task, I'd definitely start looking there. If you can upgrade to log4j 2, check them.